# Python 3.6.4, Scraping a website that requires login

Tags: python-3.x

Login Address: https://joffice.jeunesseglobal.com/login.asp.
   Two data need to put: Username and pw.
   Using cookie to access:https://joffice.jeunesseglobal.com/members/back_office.asp
   Can't login.

```
#-*-coding:utf8-*-
import  urllib
import  http.cookiejar

url = 'https://joffice.jeunesseglobal.com/members/back_office.asp'
login_url = "https://joffice.jeunesseglobal.com/login.asp"
login_username = "jianghong181818"
login_password = "Js@168168!"

login_data = {
    "Username" : login_username,
    "pw" : login_password,
}

post_data = urllib.parse.urlencode(login_data).encode('utf-8')


headers = {'User-agent':'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/60.0.3112.113 Safari/537.36'}

req = urllib.request.Request(login_url, headers = headers, data = post_data)

cookie = http.cookiejar.CookieJar()

opener = urllib.request.build_opener(urllib.request.HTTPCookieProcessor(cookie))

resp = opener.open(req)
print(resp.read().decode('utf-8'))
```

Answer (score 2):

Use requests

Simple way:

```
>>>import requests
>>>page = requests.get(" https://joffice.jeunesseglobal.com/login.asp", auth=
('username', 'password'))
```

Making requests with HTTP Basic Auth

```
>>> from requests.auth import HTTPBasicAuth
>>> requests.get(" https://joffice.jeunesseglobal.com/login.asp", auth=HTTPBasicAuth('user', 'pass'))
```

Comment: @James You would need to install requests module if you haven't already.

Comment: For all other type of authentication :http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/authentication/